# Tabbed Panel with DataViews and "Pager Save State" controls

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

**Scenario:**
1) A Tabbed Panel with three Tabs
2) Each Tab containing a DataView
3) Each DataView is categorized, collapsed as default
4) Documents may be opened and closed from views

**Present Behaviour:**
Closing a doc returns the user to the respective **collapsed** view.

**Present Code:**
1) Every DataView has in one of its pagerBottom facets a "Pager Save State" control
2) The doc's "Close" button contains: viewStateBean.restoreState = true;

**Desired Behaviour:**
Closing the doc, one should return to the view in the state in which it was left.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the code...

```
viewStateBean.restoreState=true;
```

in the "Close" button, try placing it in the "beforePageLoad" of the XPage.  This works for me when there is one DataView, so it's possible it will work with multiple.